# test cafe, select button where child span has text

Tags: html, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using material-ui buttons which put its' labels inside a span element. The button I am trying to click is next to other buttons, the only thing that makes them unique is the text in the child span element.

[image]

I have tried clicking the button like this:

```
await t.click(Selector('button').withText('button 2'));
```

But it is not working, I assume it it because `withText` is looking for text as the button child and not an additional span element as wrapper for the text?

Anyway, any suggestions on how I can click this button?

Comment: How about changing the selector? something like (".MuiButton-label") maybe that might work.

Comment: You can try await t.click(Selector('.MuiButtonBase-root').find('.MuiButton-label').withText('button2').parent('button');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mo options.

You can use `find()`:

```
await t.click(Selector('button').find('span').withExactText('button 2'));
```

or you for example use `child()`:

```
await t.click(Selector('button').child('span').withExactText('button 2'));
```

This documentation page and its subchapters might help you further: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/

Comment: Thanks. This worked! I realized that I actually already tried something very similar that also work as a way of selecting a button with child span text equals ****. What was very surprising to me is that I needed to provide uppercased text in order to find the button. `.withExactText('BUTTON 2')` because Material UI adds a css uppercase style to the text. When inspecting the element it is still lower case but the rendered text on the screen is uppercase and that must be where `withExactText`look.